# Have buttons overflow onto a second toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm looking to have a Windows Forms toolbar overflow its buttons onto a second toolbar another level down rather than having the dropdown menu.  We find that it is not obvious to our users that they need to click the dropdown to see more tools.  Suggestions?

Comment: Not to sound facetious, but you could add this to your training manual.

Comment: Well, I figure I'm about 10 years behind you.  While this may seem to be something simple to you it is new to me.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

Break your toolbar up into several smaller toolbars, like how MS Office does it. This way you can arrange them on as many rows as you like.

Comment: The problem is that the buttons are passed to my control as an array that doesn't explicitly state how they would be divided properly.

Answer (score 0):

If breaking this into multiple toolbars will not provide the user experience that you want (although it is clearly the best practice), I believe you can listen to the Resize event, and then move all items from the Items collection that have IsOnOverflow set to true to a second tool strip.